# Question about normal extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need help understanding this true/false question. It is a true statement (according to the solution in the text) but I don't understand why.

An extension $E$ of degree 2 over a field $F$ is always a normal extension of $F$ if the characteristic of $F$ is not 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think the char $2$ assumption is a red herring -- perhaps it was intended to make the problem easier via use of the quadratic formula. Anyway, if $f \in F[x]$ is irreducible but gains a root $\alpha$ in $E$ then $f$ has to be quadratic and you're allowed to divide $f$ by $x - \alpha$ inside of $E[x]$. What's left?

Answer (score 0):

If one root of a quadratic polynomial is in a field $E$ then so is the other root:
$$\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\,.$$
In other words, it is enough to extend the base field by $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$.

(Observe that there is a division by $2$ in the formula that's why characteristic $2$ is excluded.)